# rfkill unblock all does not activate a certain wireless card

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, terminal, linux-mint

With an intel 1000 wireless card;

```
rfkill list
    0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    2: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

rfkill unblock all
    0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    2: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Why does my wireless card not turn on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not invented by me, but credited to answers from others in the web. Thanks to them.

#### Initial problem:

Bought new Sony Vaio E Series. Installing using CD, Ubuntu 12.04. During installation wireless works. After reboot NO!. Can not enable wireless.

On [Dharmendra's Linux Diary](http://www.dkvermalinux.in/2012/05/ubuntu-1204-lts-wifi-problem-hardware.html?showComment=1337448079507#c2311451036067978243), I found:

```
rfkill list all
rfkill unblock all
```

`rfkill list` shows that everything works, and shows soft blocking in 'acer-wireless: Wireless LAN, soft blocked: yes`.

`rfkill unblock all` does not manage to change. After another `rfkill list all`, same status remains.

Then I learned:

```
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

It works. Wireless Networks works 'normal' as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Linux Mint with Mate.  My wireless card was a PCMCIA Cisco Aironet adapter.

The Network Manager would not display my wlan0 adapter, nor would the "Enable WiFi" option works (despite not being greyed out)

running the command `sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi` fixed it.  Card is now visible.

Additionally for reference, to make the module permnanently "unloaded":

```
'echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'
```

Thanks